# subtotal of a field in a column

Tags: sql, mariadb

how do I get this subtoal column?

| Div | Sec | sum | subtotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 3 | 8 |
| A | Y | 5 | 8 |
| A | NULL | NULL | 8 |
| B | J | 8 | 10 |
| B | K | 2 | 10 |
| B | NULL | NULL | 10 |

I am using WITH ROLLUP for subtotal row. This is just an example. Based on that subtotal column, I need to do further calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(sum) over (partition by div) as subtotal
from t;
```

Comment: ```SELECT
 Division,
 Section,
 Department,
 Assortment,
 Promo,
 `MRP Range`,
 SUM(`AL HO`)   'AL HO Stock',
 SUM(`AL STK QTY`)   'STK QTY',
 SUM(`AL SAL QTY`)   'SAL QTY',
 SUM(`AL LY(a)`)   'LY Sale (a)',
 SUM(`AL LY(b)`)   'LY Sale (b)'

FROM sum_test
 GROUP BY
  Division,
 Section,
 Department,
 Assortment,
 Promo,
 `MRP Range` WITH ROLLUP HAVING
 (Section is not null and Department is not NULL  and Assortment IS NOT  NULL AND Promo IS not NULL AND `MRP Range` IS not NULL)
 OR (Assortment IS NULL)``` could you please help me subtotal `AL SAL QTY` as subtotal please

Comment: @BrajeshSharma . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.  This one is answered.